# Callback when multiple elements loaded

Tags: javascript, html

For example, you can do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(arr, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var element = document.createElement("script");

            element.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            element.setAttribute("src", arr[i]);

            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element)
        }

        callback() // ??? When all loaded
    }
</script>
```

Is there anyway to do a callback when **all** script are done loaded?

Comment: The code in the 3rd script tag will not get executed until the first 2 scripts got loaded and executed in the order they are defined. So there's no need to listen on the "load" callback. If that's not the answer for you: You can specify the same listener for both load events and only execute code if it gets called the 2nd time. You can know this by settinga  variable to 0 and then increasing it by one on every call. Although I'd recommend using a library like `async`.

Comment: @VanCoding Edited for easier understanding

Comment: What does **both script** refers to?

Comment: @cuSK Should be "all" fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript you could do something like:

```
function load(arr, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var element = document.createElement("script");

        element.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        element.setAttribute("src", arr[i]);

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element)

        element.addEventListener("load",onLoad);
    }

    var loaded = 0;
    function onLoad(){
        if(++loaded == arr.length){
            callback()
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use promises, like Halcyon already stated, or some other libraries like `async`.

Comment: Hmm, wait, what's the difference of ++loaded and loaded++, because loaded++ doesn't work..?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you don't need to. Scripts are executed in-order.

---

Synchronizing between multiple asynchronous processes is best done with Promises.

You can do something like:

```
var p1 = new Promise();
var p2 = new Promise();
when(p1, p2).done(function () {
  // p1 and p2 are complete
});
```

Exact code depends on your chosen library/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **JavaScript snippet**:

```js
a.addEventListener("load", function() {
    b.addEventListener("load", callback());
});
```

This should solve your issue!

Comment: Be careful! What if b's load event gets called before adding the handler?

Comment: Cool, how would I like insert this in my edited code?